# I scared my cat today and he hates me

Tags: cats, aggression

I was changing the sheets today and as usual Toby likes to get under the sheets and stays for a while.

I was teasing him on top of the sheet and all if a sudden he starting yowling. I lifted the sheet and he was hissing, his ear were back and I thought he was going to attack me.

He ran out of the bedroom, hit his head on the hall door and kept running. Be spent most if the day under the bed, and when he was out he would hiss and run everytime he saw me. I am heartbroken.

Will he get over this?

Comment: will you get over it as your cat is over it by now.just take some time and play whith your cat for some time and give it some treats or its favorite food,every cat owner do scare their cat from time to time and our cats handle it quite well(it can be any thing from dropping an item on the floor to stepping on their paw).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. It's best to take it to chat if you want to debate aspects of the question.

Answer (score 7):

He's clearly a bit freaked out but I would say that he'll almost certainly get over it and you don't need to worry.

My advice would be to be as non-threatening as possible, be affectionate and give him treats but as much as you can let him come to you. If he wants to hide let him hide because that will be making him feel safe. Also, I know this is easier said than done but as best you can you need to be relaxed around him, otherwise your stress will be communicated to him which could make him more stressed out and wary.

If behavioral changes persist for more than say 48 hours it might be worth a trip to the vet as there could be an underlying medical issue causing him pain.